# Can't Connect to Meteor Web Socket through React Native

Tags: nginx, meteor, react-native, websocket, ubuntu-16.04

I am currently hosting a bundled Meteor app on Digital Ocean with nginx using [this tutorial](http://blog.shivmehra.com/2016/06/run-your-meteor-app-on-production.html?showComment=1499753234821)

I am using the react-native-meteor package in React Native to connect to this server. When the server is hosted on localhost, Meteor.connect(ws://192.168.0.2:3000/websocket) works.

Also, when the app is running on Digital Ocean, I am able to connect to the meteor server's webpage with https://XXX.XXX.X.XX after bypassing security warning and the websocket with wss://XXX.XXX.X.XX/websocket.

However, running Meteor.connect(wss://XXX.XXX.X.XX/websocket) or Meteor.connect(ws://XXX.XXX.X.XX/websocket) do not work.

Here is the nginx config:

```
server_tokens off; # for security-by-obscurity: stop displaying nginx version

# this section is needed to proxy web-socket connections
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

# HTTP
server {
    listen 80 default_server; # if this is not a default server, remove "default_server"
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html; # root is irrelevant
    index index.html index.htm; # this is also irrelevant

    server_name XXX.XXX.X.X; # the domain on which we want to host the application. Since we set "default_server" previously, nginx will answer all hosts anyway.

    # redirect non-SSL to SSL
    location / {
        rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy; # we enable SPDY here
    server_name XXX.XXX.X.X; # this domain must match Common Name (CN) in the SSL certificate

    root html; # irrelevant
    index index.html; # irrelevant

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/budget.pem; # full path to SSL certificate and CA certificate concatenated together
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/budget.key; # full path to SSL key

    # performance enhancement for SSL
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    # safety enhancement to SSL: make sure we actually use a safe cipher
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';

    # config to enable HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
    # to avoid ssl stripping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_stripping#SSL_stripping
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";

    # If your application is not compatible with IE <= 10, this will redirect visitors to a page advising a browser update
    # This works because IE 11 does not present itself as MSIE anymore
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE" ) {
        return 303 https://browser-update.org/update.html;
    }

    # pass all requests to Meteor
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP

        # this setting allows the browser to cache the application in a way compatible with Meteor
        # on every applicaiton update the name of CSS and JS file is different, so they can be cache infinitely (here: 30 days)
        # the root path (/) MUST NOT be cached
        if ($uri != '/') {
            expires 30d;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should update your question to show the error message (open you browser javascript console then refresh your link and recreate the error condition) 
 ...  your nginx config  must include these settings

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

in your nginx config as per

```
location / {

    proxy_pass http://GKE_NGINX_NODEJS_ENDUSER_SERVER_IP:3000/;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    # Include support for web sockets:
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

in addition to above assure you have this in your server block

```
server {

    server_name example.com;
```

and not the IP of the server as per :

```
    server_name XXX.XXX.X.X; # this domain must match Common Name (CN) in the SSL certificate
```

there are many moving parts ... assure you have defined the environment variable METEOR_SETTINGS prior to launching your app when you execute node

```
METEOR_SETTINGS={
  "public": {
    "rootUrl": "https://example.com",
    < ... more here ... >
  },
  "cordova": {
    "localhost": "http://localhost:12416"
  },
  < ... more here ... >
}
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I've updated the question to show the nginx config. There is no error, just a "disconnected from DDP server" from react native output.

Comment: @AdeptLearner Any breakthrough?? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @Rashmi It's been almost a year, but I think the problem was due to a missing SSL key.